How does a 50% probability prove that it happens at least once in an infinite loop?
The pigeonhole principle states that if n items are put into m containers, with n > m, then at least one container must contain more than one item.
My question is, can an event with a probability of 50 per cent be proved by the pigeonhole principle to be certain to occur once in an infinite number of cycles?
If the pigeonhole principle does not hold, are there other theories, such as the The Law of Large Numbers of probability theory, that prove that the event must occur once in an infinite number of cycles.

by Second Borel–Cantelli lemma prove.
